# Drag and drop file upload submitting immediately

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I'm following [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/) to try to figure out how to build a drag-and-drop file upload box. I can't use jQuery. The problem is that when I release a file over the box, the form automatically submits to the target specified in the form `action` property despite my trying to override it. Any ideas? I have copied out the upload box -

```
<form id="uploader" class="box" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">               
  <div class="box__input">                                                                           
      <svg class="box__icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="43" viewBox="0 0 50 43"><path d="M48.4 26.5c-.9 0-1.7.7-1.7 1.7v11.6h-43.3v-11.6c0-.9-.7-1.7-1.7-1.7s-1.7.7-1.7 1.7v13.2c0 .9.7 1.7 1.7 1.7h46.7c.9 0 1.7-.7 1.7-1.7v-13.2c0-1-.7-1.7-1.7-1.7zm-24.5 6.1c.3.3.8.5 1.2.5.4 0 .9-.2 1.2-.5l10-11.6c.7-.7.7-1.7 0-2.4s-1.7-.7-2.4 0l-7.1 8.3v-25.3c0-.9-.7-1.7-1.7-1.7s-1.7.7-1.7 1.7v25.3l-7.1-8.3c-.7-.7-1.7-.7-2.4 0s-.7 1.7 0 2.4l10 11.6z"></path></svg>                                                    
      <br>                                                                                           
      <input class="box__file" type="file" name="files[]" id="file" data-multiple-caption="{count} file selected" multiple />
    <label class="file-label" for="file"><strong>Choose a file</strong><span class="box__dragndrop"> or drag it here</span>.</label>
  </div>                                                                                             
  <div class="box__uploading">Uploading…</div>                                                       
  <div class="box__success">Done!</div>                                                              
  <div class="box__error">Error! <span></span>.</div>                                                
    <button class="box__button" type="button">Upload</button>                                        
</form>
```

and I have the following in javascript below it:

```
var isAdvancedUpload = function() {                                                                  
  var div = document.createElement('div');                                                           
  return (('draggable' in div) || ('ondragstart' in div && 'ondrop' in div)) && 'FormData' in window && 'FileReader' in window;
}();                                                                                                 
                                                                                                     
var form = document.querySelector('.box');                                                           
                                                                                                     
if (isAdvancedUpload) {                                                                              
  form.className += " " + 'has-advanced-upload';                                                     
}                                                                                                    
                                                                                                     
if (isAdvancedUpload) {                                                                              
                                                                                                     
  var droppedFiles = false;                                                                          
                                                                                                     
  'drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave drop'.split(" ").forEach(function(e) {        
      window.addEventListener(e, function(f){                                                        
          f.preventDefault();                                                                        
          f.stopPropagation();                                                                       
      }, false);                                                                                     
  });                                                                                                
                                                                                                     
  window.addEventListener('dragover',                                                                
      ()=>form.classList.add('is-dragover'),                                                         
    false                                                                                            
  );                                                                                                 
                         
  window.addEventListener('dragenter',                                                               
      ()=>form.classList.add('is-dragover'),                                                         
    false                                                                                            
  );                                                                                                 
  window.addEventListener('dragleave',                                                               
      ()=>form.classList.remove('is-dragover'),                                                      
    false                                                                                            
  );                                                                                                 
  window.addEventListener('dragend',                                                                 
      ()=>form.classList.remove('is-dragover'),                                                      
    false                                                                                            
  );                                                                                                 
  window.addEventListener('dragdrop',                                                                
      ()=>form.classList.remove('is-dragover'),                                                      
    false                                                                                            
  );                                                                                                 
  window.addEventListener('drop',                                                                    
      (e)=>{                                                                                         
        droppedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;                                                         
        console.log(droppedFiles);                                                                   
        form.submit();                                                                               
      },                                                                                             
    false                                                                                            
  );                                                                                                 
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {                                                      
      form = document.querySelector("#uploader");                                                    
      if ('is-uploading' in form.classList) return false;                                            
      form.classList.add('is-uploading');                                                            
      form.classList.remove('is-error');                                                             
      input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');                                          
                                                                                                     
      /* code here to collect the input, package it as a FormData, and fetch it to a specific POST endpoint */
```

Comment: Where are you overriding the default behaviour of submitting the form?

Comment: I think it's (1) `form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {` and (2) the `'drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter`... function which atttaches `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` to the events. But there's a good chance I'm misunderstanding, if you can help!

Comment: Can also add it on `submit' (not only return false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `drop` event handling is submitting the form. I'd try (re)moving that line. If you want to click a button to submit or something then you'll need to submit the form there.

```
  window.addEventListener('drop',                                                                    
      (e)=>{                                                                                         
        droppedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;                                                         
        console.log(droppedFiles);                                                                   
        form.submit(); // THIS LINE RIGHT HERE                                                                             
      },                                                                                             
    false                                                                                            
  );
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I would *like* the `drop` event to submit the form, just by using the function defined in the `submit` event, not by immediately sending the form to the url specified by `action`. How do I make that work?

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood. Have you tried adding `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` to suppress the behaviour of the form submit? It's not listed in `'drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave drop'`.